# Help on understanding tax bracket computation

Tags: statistics, algorithms, finance, mathematical-modeling

**Warning: some codes**

Tax Bracket:

> - `1` up to `5,070` ---- `10%`
> - `5,071` up to `8,660` ---- `14%`
> - `8,661` up to `14,070` ---- `23%`
> - `14,071` up to `21,240` ---- `30%`
> - `21,241` up to `40,230` ---- `33%`
> - Higher than `40,230` ---- `45%`

I understand the concept of **progressive tax**, wherein if I have an income of 50,000. Then each chunk of that amount that falls into the bracket will be taxed accordingly.

I searched the internet and found a sample code/program for this.

```
if (income > 40230) 
    return 0.45 * (income - 40230) + 10671.6;
else if (income > 21240)
    return 0.33 * (income - 21240) + 4404.9;
else if (income > 14070)
    return 0.30 * (income - 14070) + 2253.9;
else if (income > 8660)
    return 0.23 * (income - 8660) + 1009.6;
else if (income > 5070)
    return 0.14 * (income - 5070) + 507;
else
    return 0.10 * income;
```

---

My question to help me understand the program:

On the first `return` statement, can anyone explain where the constant `10671.6` came from? Sorry for asking this, but I can't seem to understand where it came from.
Same goes for the numbers (`4404.9`, `2253.9`, `1009.6`, `507`) on the succeeding `return` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$10671.6$ is the tax on the first $40230$, calculated as $0.1\cdot 5070+0.14(8660-5070)+0.23(14070-8660)+0.3(21240-14071)+0.33(40230-21240)$

The others are the lower pieces of this.

Comment: ohhh. thanks for this!